# How to split an array into multiple arrays based on a specific value in python

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, split

Consider I have an array of random values. In the array there is a value that is close to 0, but is not 0, that repeats consecutively at random places. What I want to do is to find these values and split the array into multiple arrays exactly at this place at the same time removing the repeating values. Restriction is that I cannot eliminate the value if it is not repeated more than twice consecutively.

For example:

```
array=np.array([-0.005,-0.004,0.00002,-0.003,0.004,0.00002,0.00002,0.00002,0.00002,
            0.005,0.003,0.00002,0.0006,0.008,0.00002,0.00002,0.00002,
            -0.003,0.006,0.007,0.00002,0.00002,0.00002])
minval=np.abs(array).min()
print(minval)
```

I find that 0.00002 is the value closest to 0, and therefore my aims is to obtain:

```
array1=([-0.005,-0.004,0.00002,-0.003,0.004],[0.005,0.003,0.00002,0.0006,0.008],[-0.003,0.006,0.007])
```

Is there a convenient way to do that in Python?

Comment: is your output consistent with your restriction ? **Restriction is that I cannot eliminate the value if it is not repeated more than twice consecutively.** ? if i understand the second array `0.3,0.4,0.2,0.5.0.3`?

Comment: You should describe what you have done to solve this task.What have & what haven't worked. This way other users can help you our better
You need to do basic research before posting the task. Thanks for understanding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve that relatively easy with iterator:

```py
import numpy as np

def split_by_min(arr):
    equals = np.isclose(arr, np.abs(arr).min())

    l = []
    is_ready = False
    for i in range(len(arr)):
        if equals[i] and i < len(arr)-1 and equals[i+1]:
            is_ready = True
        elif not equals[i] and is_ready:
            yield l
            l = []
            is_ready = False

        if not is_ready:
            l.append(arr[i])

    yield l




arr = np.array([-0.005,-0.004,0.00002,-0.003,0.004,0.00002,0.00002,0.00002,
                0.00002,0.005,0.003,0.00002,0.0006,0.008,0.00002,0.00002,
                0.00002,-0.003,0.006,0.007,0.00002,0.00002,0.00002])

for l in split_by_min(arr):
    print(l)
```

Output:

```
[-0.005, -0.004, 2e-05, -0.003, 0.004]
[0.005, 0.003, 2e-05, 0.0006, 0.008]
[-0.003, 0.006, 0.007]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this:

```
import numpy as np
array=np.array([-0.005,-0.004,0.00002,-0.003,0.004,0.00002,0.00002,0.00002,0.00002,
            0.005,0.003,0.00002,0.0006,0.008,0.00002,0.00002,0.00002,
            -0.003,0.006,0.007,0.00002,0.00002,0.00002])
absArr = np.abs(array)
min_val=absArr.min()
idx = np.where(absArr == min_val)[0]

grad= idx[1:] - idx[:-1]

arrs = []
for l,u,g in zip(idx[:-1],idx[1:],grad):
    print(l,u,g)
    if g > 1:
        arrs.append(array[l:u])
```

Then `arrs` has this content:

```
[[ 2.e-05 -3.e-03  4.e-03],
[2.e-05 5.e-03 3.e-03],
[2.e-05 6.e-04 8.e-03],
[ 2.e-05 -3.e-03  6.e-03  7.e-03]]
```